# Redshift - Find percentage of contribution by category

Tags: sql, select, count, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have my data in the below format:

```
product, person
prod_a, person_1
prod_a, person_2
prod_a, person_3
prod_b, person_1
```

I am trying to find the percent contributed by each person per product. Expected output is :

```
product, person, prct
prod_a, person_1, 0.33
prod_a, person_2, 0.33
prod_a, person_3, 0.33
prod_b, person_1, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select
    product,
    person,
    1.0 * count(*) over(partition by product, person) 
        / count(*) over(partition by product) as prct
from mytable
```

If, as shown in your sample data, there are no duplicate `(product, person)` tuples, then it is a bit simpler:

```
select
    product,
    person,
    1.0 / count(*) over(partition by product) as prct
from mytable
```